# Surge/signal protection for low voltage ECG leads

Tags: diodes, ecg

ECG leads generally see voltages in the range of -5mV to 5mV and a frequency range of .05Hz - 150Hz.  We are peripherally stimulating the patients with up to 200v at a frequency of 1kHz elsewhere on the body for about 100mSec and it disrupts our front-end ECG chip.  I need to protect the ECG leads from the stimulation.  Although the system recovers, it takes far too long.  How could we do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this has been solved before with defibrillators.
Google search for "ECG defibrillator protection circuit".
First result: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/5/5724.html
You may find application notes on what protection circuitry to use with it in your chip's datasheet or similar chip's datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sources of trouble:

1. The body transforms some of the stimulation signal into differential mode ECG inputs. This is largely out of our control.
2. The common mode currents flow through the isolated ECG front-end, and get converted to differential signal by the asymmetries in the electrode resistance, lead parasitics, and the front-end itself.

It is worth evaluating which of these two dominates, to inform subsequent line of attack. It may be that neither is clearly dominant and their proportion is highly patient- as well as electrode-placement dependent. Then a two-front attack is needed :)

There are several approaches that can mitigate trouble, and often a combination of those may be necessary.

1. Common-mode current minimization

   1. Minimize the common-mode signal injected into the body by the stimulator: cut down the isolation capacitance in the stimulator's supply, maintain physical symmetry from the push-pull stimulus driver circuitry all the way to the patient, and symmetry of the parasitics from each leg of the stimulus circuit to the ground - as well as practicable. This must be done while monitoring the common-mode current, so that any improvements will have quantitative backing.
   2. Minimize the common-mode current flowing through the ECG front end: evaluate parasitics at 1kHz, and systematically cut it down as far as you can. Again, measure the current and ensure that improvements actually decrease it.
   3. Evaluate the CMRR of the ECG front-end at 1kHz, and work to improve it - usually by meticulous attention to symmetry of the layout, choosing ICs with pinouts that maintain symmetry, and by balancing parasitics between the front-end nodes and the shield. It is often that such balancing is frequency-specific and may even slightly degrade performance at lower frequencies. It's a tradeoff.
   4. Bootstrap the common mode in the stimulator and/or the ECG front-end. One approach is to purposefully leak a small common mode signal from the stimulator's driver into the ECG front-end. This requires that the stimulator and the ECG front-ends are in the same enclosure, so that such a leakage could be arranged without disturbing other parasitics. This of course requires closed-loop control of both the phase and the amplitude of the leakage current.
2. Differential-mode mitigation for leftover common mode that gets converted to differential mode:

   1. Short the differential mode at 1kHz using a passive network.
   2. Short the differential mode at 1kHz using a selective buffer. Think of a voltage follower from one differential input to another. That would be a hard short. But make the buffer selective, so that it's only sensitive to signal in-phase with the 1kHz excitation, and also so that its effective output impedance is infinite away from 1kHz. The buffer's input and output impedance across frequencies of interest must be well matched so that it doesn't degrade CMRR rejection and/or make the buffer unstable. This can be hard to do.

An ECG front-end for a general-purpose use would include defibrillator protection. Such protection networks are *extremely* hard to make fully symmetric without an expensive to implement trimming process, and they invariably degrade CMRR while protecting the in-amp from getting destroyed. They are a trade-off. If you don't need defibrillator protection in this application, then each stage of the protection circuitry must be evaluated for its impact on CMRR, and potentially removed. There's often lots of interaction between protection stages, and their relative contributions may change as the network is decimated.

Also, some kinds of ECG front-ends are much better suited for interoperating with audio-frequency interference signals. For example, instead of an in-amp, you may find that using a sensitive sigma-delta ADC, connected "directly" to electrodes, works just as well. It's then critical to keep the DC bias paths local to the front-end, of course: the connection isn't really "direct", but uses no further gain stages external to the ADC.

If you run the ADC's clock synchronously with the 1kHz reference clock, it may well be able to inherently reject this interference, or at least its phase and amplitude will be consistent enough to allow removal in software without artifacts and without the interfering frequency being smeared around too much.

With a lot of attention to detail, which may or may not be in the budget or even feasible in your application, it is entirely possible to acquire uncorrupted ECG **while** strong narrowband interfering signals are present. So it wouldn't be about "recovery" but about actually having uninterrupted, clean(ish) ECG signal whether the 1kHz stimulus is present or absent. That's the ideal case, and it's possible, but last time I did something similar (with EOG not ECG), it was a lot of work.